# How to enable Hermes in react native cli version "0.71.2"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to enable Hermes in React Native cli version "0.71.2"? Can anyone guide me through every step that I need to take to enable Hermes in React Native cli version "0.71.2"?

I found some resources on the internet but after following every step told it caused me build fail errors I also tried to use a library called **"@react-native-community/hermes" but now in the new version of rn cli it was not found in registry**

**How can I enable hermes in new versions of React Native cli app?**